# Mac address of Tails in VirtualBox

Tags: tails, virtual-machine, virtualisation

On Tor website they type `The MAC address of the computer is not modified by the MAC address spoofing feature of Tails when run in a virtual machine.`
But I'm running Tor in VirtualBox and I just checked my MAC address of Host Machine and Mac address of Tails that is running in VirtualBox and MAC addresses differ. Why ?

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to explain using this scheme:

[image]

I may be wrong, I'm not a very active Tails user.

Answer (score 1):

The host machine has a mac and the virtual machine also has a mac (not related to host machine's mac), tails spoofs the mac on the virtual machine - not the host machine.

This means :
Host machine's mac is never modified by tails when you run it in virtualbox.
But the virtual machine's mac is modified by tails.

You can check the virtual machine's mac in the settings panel, you will then see it differently in tails, but the host machine's mac will not be spoofed unless you run tails directly on your hardware through USB stick \ DVD.